# Importing specific date format to Excel from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, date-format

I'm importing dates from a German SQL Server table into a German Excel file via the built-in Excel connection tool.

However the date format is just like in the SQL Server: `2012-08-08` but I want to display: `08.08.2012`. When I double-click inside a cell it will recognize the German date formatting but of course I would like to have that format for the entire column without having to manually change it.

I also need to be able to use these dates for calculations.

Do I need to change something in SQL Server or how do I make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: might be better on superuser.com, if custom Excel formatting is an acceptable answer

Comment: thanks for the link - I'll try my luck there as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Excel does not recognise the SQL Server Date type.  Cast the date to a Smalldatetime or Datetime, then import and format.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's recognized ad a date, you can set the formatting of the entire column to a custom one and set the value of the custom format to `dd.mm.yyyy` (or `mm.dd.yyyy`, depending on which you want).

Not a *programming* answer, but it will get you the display you want just by setting the custom format of the whole column.